# ERROR IN StoredProcedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UploadFile] (
@FileName VARCHAR(150),
@FileSize INT,
@FileContentType VARCHAR(200),
@FileExtension VARCHAR(10),
@FileContent VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO FilesData( FileName,FileSize,FileContentType,FileExtension,FileContent ) VALUES
  ( @FileName,@FileSize,@FileContentType,@FileExtension,@FileContent )
END
```

> this SaveFile.cs

```
    public class SaveFile
{
    public string FileName { set; get; }
    public string FileExtension { set; get; }
    public byte[] FileContent { set; get; }

    public string SaveFileToDB()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"D:\\TinyShare\\App_Data\\TinyShareDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True" + "Initial Catalog=TinyShareDB_log.ldf;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
            cmd.CommandText = "UploadFile";
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileContent", FileContent);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileExtension", FileExtension);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", FileExtension);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileContentType", FileExtension);


            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return "File stored Successfully!!!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
     }}
```

[Error in alter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNB4d.png)

Comment: Can you paste the entire error message? Also, are you doing that through SSMS or another tool.

Comment: Does the table FilesData has any Key, non-nullable field?

Comment: What is the content of `ex.Message`?

Comment: The request for procedure 'UploadFile' failed because 'UploadFile' is a table object.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Helpful items include the database software, e.g. SQL Server 2016, `FilesData` schema, complete error message, when the error is generated, e.g. when you execute the `ALTER PROCEDURE` or run the application, ... . And your connection string doesn't look right. The quoting and addition don't seem to produce a reasonable string.

Answer (score 0):

1. Specify your database with `USE statement`.
2. Don't use alter, but prefer drop and create systax.
3. Check if your object exists before create.

   ```
   use DbName
   go
   if object_id('YourProc') is null drop procedure YourProc
   create YourProc...
   ```

If you move your mouse pointer above red underlined text, you will get detailed error description.

Your `ALTER` is underlined because your object probably don't exist yet or cannot reach this object because your script doesn't know where is your procedure.